# Error: ethjs-query while formatting outputs from RPC

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am having the following contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./IERC165.sol";
import "./IERC721.sol";
import "./IERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "./ERC165.sol";
import "./Strings.sol";
import "./Address.sol";
import "./IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "./IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";

contract rNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string baseURI; //NFT json is saved
    string linkURL;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost; // = 0.0 ether;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 1;
    bool public isInVault = false;

    event Logging(string value);

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // public
    function mint(string memory _linkURL) public payable returns (uint) {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        uint256 tokenID = supply + 1;

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            require(msg.value >= cost);
        }

        emit Logging(_linkURL);
        setLinkURL(_linkURL);

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenID);

        return tokenID;
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function setIsInVault() public onlyOwner {
        isInVault = true;
    }

    function setLinkURL(string memory _linkUrl) public onlyOwner {
        linkURL = _linkUrl;
    }

    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        // This will pay 5% of the initial sale. 
        (bool hs, ) = payable(0x8fc7Bb7494D4C000fb0b37ee2166ae23502073E0).call{value: address(this).balance * 10 / 100}("");
        require(hs);

        // Do not remove this otherwise you will not be able to withdraw the funds.
        (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(os);
    }
}
```

Basically, when I mint an NFT I would like to write a specific url additionally on the blockchain.

So the NFT can be identified by its token ID, but also by the identifier, whereas the identifier is a specific link `linkURL`.

When calling the following javascript mint function I get an error:

```
  const IDENTIFIER = "/myIdentifier";
  const blockchain = useSelector((state) => state.blockchain);
...

  const claimNFTs = () => {
    let cost = 200000000000000000;
    let gasLimit = 3000000;
    let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount);
    let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
    blockchain.smartContract.methods
      .mint(IDENTIFIER)
      .send({
        gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
        to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        from: blockchain.account,
        value: totalCostWei,
      })
      .once("error", () => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .then((receipt) => {
        console.log(receipt);
      });
  };
```

I get the following error:

```
'[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Ownable: caller is not the owner","code":-32000,"data":{"0xcf9c12e58bf28a20a91bce248f1568263f4744bc31f7220f39e3add21a93ce4b":{"error":"revert","program_counter":5034,"return":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000204f776e61626c653a2063616c6c6572206973206e6f7…ile processing transaction: revert Ownable: caller is not the owner\\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachUzdgcN/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganachUzdgcN/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}''
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: The answer identified the problem correctly and offers the solution, you should mark it as correct and give the bounty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is `caller is not the owner`, that's because the contract inherits from `Ownable` and had the deployer defined as the owner.

It probably happens because the caller "blockchain.account" isn't the owner.

The `mint` function calls `setLinkURL` which has the `onlyOwner` modifier, so it requires de-facto the caller of `mint` to be the owner, even though it doesn't have that modifier itself.

You either need to call `mint` using the account that deployed it, or change `mint` to not requiring `onlyOwner` due to `setLinkURL`.